# Inline column vectors appear too big

Tags: amsmath, vector

When I use a vector within the text, the vector appears too big - how can I make it smaller?

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line. 
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A non-typesetting answer is, of course, to write $(0 1)^T$.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I prefer `$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}^T$` because it is more clearear what are you using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `psmallmatrix` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\begin{psmallmatrix}1\\0\end{psmallmatrix}$.
    Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line. 
    How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can either use the `psmallmatrix` environment from `mathtools`, or the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` (ca 80 % of `\displaystyle`), or  make a group in footnotesize. Just choose:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document} 

One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line.
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?

One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\begin{psmallmatrix}1\\0\end{psmallmatrix}$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line.
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?


One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\medmath{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}}$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line.
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?
?

One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is {\scriptsize$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$}.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line.
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

try with `smallmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line.
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I simply would use the command `\tbinom{1}{0}` at the [pag.18](http://www.icl.utk.edu/~mgates3/docs/latex.pdf) of this guide:

[image]

I think it could be a good compromise, it is a simple basic command and it is not too big. See the figure below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
One standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\tbinom{1}{0}$.
 Unfortunately, the vector is about twice as tall as the rest of the line. 
How can I reduce its size to about $1.5$-times the size of the line?
\end{document}
```